# How to create a 0 byte file in ksh.

Tags: unix, ksh

This is probably obvious, but Google seems to have let me down. I need to create a zero byte file with arbitrary names on Unix (AIX, ksh). What is a good command that will do this. Something I can script obviously.

Just to be clear Im not doing anything stupid. This is a script to generate certain testing scenarios. (Checking proper behavior when handling 0-byte files.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save your keystrokes and the unnecessary process, redirection will do:

```
$ > file
$ ls
file
```

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out.

`touch $filename` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=zero.out bs=0 count=0
```

Comment: @JesperE provided a nice option.  Another option is to be more assertive: `x="I need a 0 byte file" ; echo -n $x | tr -d "[:print:]" > outfile`